# Living in Florida working remotely - NY employer withholds NYS taxes - Correct or Incorrect?

Tags: united-states, state-income-tax, new-york, florida

This question has been asked before but the answer was inconclusive.

Moving to Florida was my personal decision. My employer agreed to let me continue in the same job working remotely.

NYS tax for the 2015 was withheld by my employer but unemployment insurance was paid to FL. Is this correct or incorrect?

Comment: Do you mean unemployment insurance tax? If so, how do you know where that was paid? That's not usually information shared with employees.

Comment: I asked what change was required before I moved and an account to pay unemployment insurance tax was subsequently opened with state of FL.  Small firm so information is easily shared.

Comment: Stephen yes it's been asked before but the answers were more argumentative than conclusive for someone with no experience in the subject matter.

Comment: I'm going to vote to close this question as duplicate, but I'm posting an answer on the original question since you didn't find what was already there sufficient. As regards the UI tax - I believe your employer is doing that correctly, although that has 0 impact on your personal situation, i.e. even if they were doing that wrong, you owe the same taxes and have the same benefits.